# My function does not return anything

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to make a function that calculates the occurence of a given letter in a word.The problem the code is error-free but it doesn't return the occurence number when I call the function

```
def countSubStringMatchRecursive(key, target):
    if find(target, key)==-1:
        occ = 0
        return occ  
    else:
        countSubStringMatchRecursive(key, target[find(target, key)+1:])
        occ = 1 + countSubStringMatchRecursive(key, target[find(target, key)+1:])  
        return occ
print occ
countSubStringMatchRecursive('a', 'sapatara')
```

Comment: Put the actual code here not just a img

Comment: It looks like your indentation is bogus.

Comment: you can still post code.

Comment: @Yassine: Anybody can put code in their posts. It's the central feature of the site :-) Simply copy paste it in, select it, and press the 'Code Sample' formatting button.

Comment: the name of your function is hilariously long for some non business code

Comment: it's an assignement so...

Comment: "the code is error-free" - if you can't find any errors in your code, but it doesn't work, it's not error-free.

Comment: I mean when I compiled it APPARENTLY nothing is wrong with it. the execution in the other hand.. !!

Comment: Also, this code doesn't even compile. You have mismatched parentheses and brackets. Either you haven't posted your real code, or you looked at a screen with an arrow pointing right at an error in your code and thought, "looks error-free".

Comment: There is a missing close paren in this line: `occ=1+countSubStringMatchRecursive(key,target[find(target,key+1:])` (the find() function is not closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling a global find function that doesn't exist. Try `target.find(key)` instead

Edit: looking closer, you have a few errors and some poor style. Here's an edited version of your function that does what you want:

```
>>> def countsub(key, target):
      i = target.find(key)
...   if i==-1:
...     return 0
...   else:
...     return 1 + countsub(key, target[i+1:]) 
... 
>>> countsub('a', 'apatara')
4
>>>
```

Comment: I've imported from string import*